# Can I set same Apple ID for iOS & Mac app?

Tags: ios, macos, app-store-connect

I have the same app for iOS and Mac. To making things more easy I want to point the iOS & Mac app with same link etc.

Is there any way to do that? I couldn't even set same Bundle ID. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't. `Bundle ID` and `App ID` are identifiers. Different Bundles/Apps have different IDs. Otherwise they aren't identifiers anymore.

If you want have one url for both, you could write a script (e.g. php), wich checks the OS running on the device and redirects to the corresponding `iTunes` link.